# I want to select a date from the popup using selenium webdriver script

Tags: date, selenium-webdriver, datepicker

[image]

I want to select 20-April-2015 from the popup. I am trying to use xpath notation for this. Kindly let me know if it is a correct way to achieve this or not.

below is he xpath I am trying, dont know if it is correct or not (partially though)

//td[@data-year="2015" and @data-month="3"]

Comment: WebElement e13 = d1.findElementByXPath("id('ui-datepicker-div')/x:div[2]/x:table/x:tbody/x:tr[4]/x:td[2]/x:a");
 e13.click();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Xpath specified above is very very fragile.
Would you always like to keep calculating the the tr,td index if the date you want to select is changed ?

Here is a better alternative, depends on the date picker object you are trying to work with, but the approach is more robust -

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class WhiteBoard {

public static WebDriver browser;

//Specify any date here... (Let it come in any format but break it up this way)
public static String day = "31";
public static String month = "January";
public static int year = 2010;

public static String test_URL = "http://salman-w.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jquery-ui-datepicker/parse-and-format-dates.html";
public static String css_DatePicker = "input.hasDatepicker";
public static String css_next = "a[title='Next']";
public static String css_prev = "a[title='Prev']";
public static String css_DispYear = "span.ui-datepicker-year";
public static String css_DispMonth = "span.ui-datepicker-month";
public static String css_DispDay = "td[data-handler='selectDay']";

public static void main(String[] args){

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\00_FX_WorkSpace\\chromedriver.exe");

    browser = new ChromeDriver();
    browser.navigate().to(test_URL);

    List<WebElement> objDate = browser.findElements(By.cssSelector(css_DatePicker));
    if(objDate.size() > 0){

        objDate.get(0).click();
        selectDate();
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Not found date object...");
    }

}

public static void selectDate(){
    selectYear();
}

public static void selectYear(){

    WebElement dispYear = browser.findElement(By.cssSelector(css_DispYear));
    int iYear = Integer.parseInt(dispYear.getText());
    if(iYear == year){
        selectMonth();
    }
    else if(iYear < year){
        //click next
        WebElement next = browser.findElement(By.cssSelector(css_next));
        next.click();
        selectYear();
    }
    else if(iYear > year){
        WebElement prev = browser.findElement(By.cssSelector(css_prev));
        prev.click();
        selectYear();
    }
}

public static void selectMonth(){

    WebElement dispMonth = browser.findElement(By.cssSelector(css_DispMonth));
    String strMonth = dispMonth.getText();

    List<String> arrMonths = new ArrayList<>();

    arrMonths.add("January");
    arrMonths.add("February");
    arrMonths.add("March");
    arrMonths.add("April");
    arrMonths.add("May");
    arrMonths.add("June");
    arrMonths.add("July");
    arrMonths.add("August");
    arrMonths.add("September");
    arrMonths.add("October");
    arrMonths.add("November");
    arrMonths.add("December");


    int iActualPosition, iExpectedPosition;
    iActualPosition = arrMonths.indexOf(strMonth);
    iExpectedPosition = arrMonths.indexOf(month);

    if(iActualPosition == iExpectedPosition){
        selectDay();
    }
    else if(iActualPosition < iExpectedPosition){
        //click next
        WebElement next = browser.findElement(By.cssSelector(css_next));
        next.click();
        selectMonth();
    }
    else if(iActualPosition > iExpectedPosition){
        WebElement prev = browser.findElement(By.cssSelector(css_prev));
        prev.click();
        selectMonth();
    }

}

public static void selectDay(){
    List<WebElement> dispDay = browser.findElements(By.cssSelector(css_DispDay));
    for (WebElement dayCell : dispDay)
    {
        if (dayCell.getText().equals(day))
        {
            dayCell.click();
            break;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I have been able to achieve this by using this code snippet:WebElement e12 =  d1.findElementById("departuredatetime");
 e12.click();

 d1.findElementByLinkText("Next").click();
 d1.findElementByXPath(".//*[@id='ui-datepicker-div']/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[3]/a").click();

Comment: Firepath gives very accurate results to detect the xpath.

Comment: Further I optimised the code in 3 lines:   d1.findElementById("departuredatetime").click();
d1.findElementByLinkText("Next").click();
d1.findElementByXPath(".//*[@id='ui-datepicker-div']/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[3]/a").click();

Comment: @Harsh I agree that you just want a forward date, but the above solution will work for any date/month/year combination. Your Xpath still has specific indexes of tr/td which is specific to a particular date. In your snippet, what if the month is to be changed, how would you handle it? BTW, Thanks for accepting it as a solution :)

Comment: @Dharam..we can reach to that month using next and back buttons and then we can select a particular data cell. Surely, the data cell that we read by this approach will be static which means that we will be selecting only one particular date field everytime we hit the calendar box, but yes we can control which month need to be selected. I think it should work fine in generic case as well. Yes in current scenario I am more concerned with forwrd and backward dates.

Comment: Yes, so in that case you will need additional logic (as in the snippet) to handle(compare) the month and Year that is being selected. For date you may get the exact Xpath (with index). Consider that current Month is March and you want to Select May, how would you determine how many "Next" button clicks to do ? Similarly if you want year to be say 2017 how would you determine how many clicks ? In this case, always have a generic functionality that can work for any date objects throughout your AUT.

Comment: Well I agree with you Dharam..but I need to explore this part in detail..right now this scenario is out of scope for my project requirement.